# Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Error opening job jar: ex.jar in hadoop

Tags: java, select, hadoop

Can someone explain how to resolve this error:

```
    Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:127)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:135)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:122)<code>*/
```

Comment: Your code is not correct.The `.jar` you have created is not in the proper form , it might be missing some `conf` to be set. So `hadoop jar` is not able to open it.Add your `driver` file [file with main] to your question

Comment: It is clearly the case of incorrect/improperly created jar file. Or if you are uploading it somewhere, so the transfer hasn't happened properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but it took a while to figure out that, when we create a new jar, the .class files in bin might not be new compiled so, make sure to delete old .class files in bin folder. I thought jar creation made replaced old .class files but i guess not. give it a try.