# No job jar file found. User classes may not be used

Tags: hadoop

I have tried to browse many of the blogs on this issue, but had no luck. I am not sure what is the mistake I am doing here.. Can somebody help me with this!

My program is:

```
package hadoopbook;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;


public class WordCount {

    //Mapper
    public static class WcMapperDemo extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

        Text MapKey = new Text();
        IntWritable MapValue = new IntWritable();

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text Value, Context Context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
            String Record = Value.toString();
            String[] Words = Record.split(",");

            for (String Word:Words){
                MapKey.set(Word);
                MapValue.set(1);
                Context.write(MapKey, MapValue);
            }   
        }
    }

    //Reducer
    public static class WcReducerDemo extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>{

        IntWritable RedValue = new IntWritable();

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> Values, Context Context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
            int sum = 0;

            for (IntWritable Value:Values){
                sum = sum + Value.get();
            }
            RedValue.set(sum);
            Context.write(key, RedValue);
        }
    }

    //Driver
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Configuration Conf = new Configuration();

        Job Job = new Job(Conf, "Word Count Job");

        Job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
        Job.setMapperClass(WcMapperDemo.class);
        Job.setReducerClass(WcReducerDemo.class);

        Job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        Job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        Job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        Job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(Job, new Path (args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(Job, new Path (args[1]));

        System.exit(Job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0:1);
    }
}
```

and the error I get is this by executing this command:

```
[cloudera@localhost Desktop]$ sudo -u hdfs hadoop jar WordCount.jar hadoopbook.WordCount /user/cloudera/InputFiles/Small/Words.txt /user/cloudera/Output
```

and I have the WordCount.jar file on my desktop folder!

```
[cloudera@localhost Desktop]$ sudo -u hdfs hadoop jar WordCount.jar hadoopbook.WordCount /user/cloudera/InputFiles/Small/Words.txt /user/cloudera/Output
14/11/06 02:56:15 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
14/11/06 02:56:15 WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
14/11/06 02:56:15 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
14/11/06 02:56:16 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201411040035_0017
14/11/06 02:56:17 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
14/11/06 02:56:29 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201411040035_0017_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class hadoopbook.WordCount$WcMapperDemo not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1617)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getMapperClass(JobContextImpl.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:631)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:330)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class hadoopbook.WordCount$WcMapperDemo not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1523)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1615)
    ... 8 more

14/11/06 02:56:36 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201411040035_0017_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class hadoopbook.WordCount$WcMapperDemo not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1617)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getMapperClass(JobContextImpl.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:631)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:330)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class hadoopbook.WordCount$WcMapperDemo not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1523)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1615)
    ... 8 more

14/11/06 02:56:42 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201411040035_0017_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class hadoopbook.WordCount$WcMapperDemo not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1617)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getMapperClass(JobContextImpl.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:631)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:330)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class hadoopbook.WordCount$WcMapperDemo not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1523)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1615)
    ... 8 more

14/11/06 02:56:54 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201411040035_0017
14/11/06 02:56:54 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 7
14/11/06 02:56:54 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters 
14/11/06 02:56:54 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Failed map tasks=1
14/11/06 02:56:54 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=4
14/11/06 02:56:54 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Data-local map tasks=4
14/11/06 02:56:54 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=33819
14/11/06 02:56:54 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
14/11/06 02:56:54 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
14/11/06 02:56:54 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
```

I tried this just now, but no luck! I have ensured that my file is there in desktop!

```
[cloudera@localhost ~]$ sudo -u hdfs hadoop jar /home/cloudera/Desktop/WordCount.jar hadoopbook.WordCount /user/cloudera/InputFiles/Small/Words.txt /user/cloudera/Output
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Error opening job jar: /home/cloudera/Desktop/WordCount.jar
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:135)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:127)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:135)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:133)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following command

```
>hadoop jar <<absolute path to WordCount.jar>> hadoopbook.WordCount /user/cloudera/InputFiles/Small/Words.txt /user/cloudera/Output
```

Comment: Hi Vijay! Just tried that, but no luck! It gives me another error. I have given the error details in my actual question! Can you please help me!

Comment: Probably below links might be useful                                                   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19093327/error-while-trying-to-run-jar-in-hadoop                                                                              http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788865/exception-in-thread-main-java-io-ioexception-error-opening-job-jar-ex-jar-in

Comment: Tried that Vijay! Had no luck!

I am unable to copy the jar to HDFS!!

[cloudera@localhost ~]$ sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/cloudera/Desktop/WordCount.jar /user/cloudera/Programs/WordCount.jar
copyFromLocal: `/home/cloudera/Desktop/WordCount.jar': No such file or directory

Comment: If you are executing in pseudo-distributed mode then the jar file can be in local filesystem.             And prefix ** sudo -u hdfs ** is not required in the above command.

Comment: Thank you Vijay! At least it started accepting the files now, but I am stuck with a new problem.. I have updated my actual question.

Comment: Thank you Vijay! I have re-installed Hadoop and followed your above suggestion and things started moving. Thank you so much!